# Trouble Installing Play Framework on Mac

Tags: shell, playframework

I'm having some difficulty installing Play on my mac.

I've successfully installed the program after running

> export PATH=/path/to/activator-x.x.x:$PATH

But, I can't run the activator command. It says that activator: command not found.

I tried running

> chmod u+x /path/to/activator-x.x.x/activator

But, I just get the "no such file or directory" message.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove the `export PATH` part, open a new terminal and execute it using the full path (ex `/Users/yourname/activator-1.3.10-minimal/bin/activator`). Check that `activator` has execute permissions and that you have Java 8 installed (`java -version`). If you still have problems post the exact activator version and java you are using

Comment: The `PATH` must include the path to the `bin` directory, not to the activator home

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to install activator successfully, you can do it with the help of `HomeBrew` which is a software management tool. Type the following command

```
brew install typesafe-activator
```

if you have not installed `HomeBrew`, you can install it using the following command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Good luck with you

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the export command to the login profile. Usually, this is $HOME/.profile. This file is referred to whenever you open a command shell and thus the system knows the path to activator. If you run the export command directly in the command shell then it will be available only for that session and not when you open a new shell. [Here](https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/) is a tutorial to edit your .profile file.